# Performance Wise: which is better in Laravel Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have been using laravel for a while now and I was just curious about which is more better for performance. Taking this scenario, I have two tables a **department** table and a **unit** table with the following structure

**DEPARTMENT TABLE**

```
Field       Type               Null       Key
----------  ----------------   -------    ------
id          int(10) unsigned   NO         PRIMARY    
name        varchar(255)       NO
```

**UNIT TABLE**

```
Field          Type               Null    Key     
-------------  ----------------   ------  ------  
id             int(10) unsigned  (NULL)   PRIMARY    
unit           varchar(255)      (NULL)                             
department_id  int(10) unsigned  (NULL)   FOREIGN
created_at     timestamp         (NULL)   
updated_at     timestamp         (NULL)
```

In the `Department` model I have `Unit` with `hasMany` and in `unit` model I have department with `belongsTo`

Now my question is if I want to get all units in a department which approach is best between **approach one** and **approach two**

**APPROACH ONE**

```
$department = Department::find($id);
$units = $department->unit;
```

**APPROACH TWO**

```
$units = DB::table('units AS a')
         ->select(array('a.id AS id','department_id', 'unit'))
         ->join('departments AS b', 'a.department_id', '=', 'b.id')
         ->where('b.id', '=', $id)
         ->get();
```

which approach is faster and better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**APPROACH ONE** by far.

If really exists a difference in which is faster, we will be talking about micro-optimization, and for these cases we will go for the cleaner and most understandable way, so the first one.

Also I would like to recommend other improvements:

One department has many units, so the relationship name should be `units`, not `unit`.

`$units = $department->units;`

Also use implicit binding when you can.

```
public function yourMethod (Department $department)
{
    $units = $department->units;
    return view('your-view', compact('units'));
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I reproduced an example on my project with [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), these are the results for 5 executions with each query:

**APPROACH ONE**:

- 320μs
- 310μs
- 300μs
- 320μs
- 320μs

~314μs

**APPROACH TWO**:

- 310μs
- 330μs
- 360μs
- 300μs
- 310μs

~322μs

As you can see, there is no difference, or at least it is insignificant. So, having the same performance, you should go for the first approach because is better quality code.

Comment: but dont you think that approach one will make two db calls

Comment: @GhostWorker Answer updated, check it. The number of calls is the same on both approaches: 1.

Comment: your effort is very much appreciated a